# Call a static method of class from another class width '$this'

Tags: php, class, methods, static

I've got some problem.
I want to call `static` method of class from another class.
Class name and method are created dynamically.

It's not really hard to do like:

```
$class = 'className';
$method = 'method';

$data = $class::$method();
```

BUT, i want to to do it like this

```
class abc {
    static public function action() {
        //some code
    }
}

class xyz {
    protected $method = 'action';
    protected $class = 'abc';

    public function test(){
        $data = $this->class::$this->method();
    }
}
```

And it doesn't work if i don't assign `$this->class` to a `$class` variable, and `$this->method` to a `$method` variable.
What's the problem?

Comment: `$this` always point at the current object - the one that the method is executing in. you can't use `$this` and magically have it become some other object's "this". And even if you could do `$this->$class->action()`, `$class` is just a string. it's not an object, and doesn't point at an instance of an object, so you can't use to execute a method in an object, even if that string is the name of some object. the only thing you could use it for is calling a **STATIC** method of the class it represents.

Answer (score 1):

The object syntax `$this->class`, `$this->method` makes it ambiguous to the parser when combined with `::` in a static call.  I've tried every combination of variable functions/string interpolation such as `{$this->class}::{$this->method}()`, etc... with no success.  So assigning to a local variable is the only way, or call like this:

```
$data = call_user_func(array($this->class, $this->method));

$data = call_user_func([$this->class, $this->method]);

$data = call_user_func("{$this->class}::{$this->method}");
```

If you need to pass arguments use [call_user_func_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php).

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 7.0 you can use the code like this:

```
<?php
class abc {
 static public function action() {
  return "Hey";
 }
}

class xyz {
 protected $method = 'action';
 protected $class = 'abc';

 public function test(){
  $data = $this->class::{$this->method}();

  echo $data;
 }
}

$xyz = new xyz();
$xyz->test();
```

For PHP 5.6 and lower you can use the [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) function:

```
<?php
class abc {
 static public function action() {
  return "Hey";
 }
}

class xyz {
 protected $method = 'action';
 protected $class = 'abc';

 public function test(){
  $data = call_user_func([
      $this->class,
      $this->method
  ]);
  echo $data;
 }
}

$xyz = new xyz();
$xyz->test();
```